# How do I compile my code in Eclipse using keyboard shortcut key 

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I compile my code in Eclipse using keyboard shortcut key? I have Googled this but could not find any answer.

In addition, if you know how to move through different tabs in Eclipse using keyboard short cut key, please tell me that too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> how to move through different tabs in eclipse using keyboard short cut
>   key

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>, and then tap <kbd>F6</kbd> to navigate through the tabs.

> How do I compile my code in eclipse using keyboard shortcut key ?

The shortcut key can be found in the respective menu item. For a list of all Eclipse shortcut keys, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

---

Reference: [Effective Eclipse: Shortcut keys](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key).

Answer (score 3):

For full project it is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (build all), this will compile your code. For individual java class please use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>J</kbd>, this will compile and run the java application.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse to find out about the existing keyboard shortcuts or to change them, go to `Window` menu, click `Preferences`, in left sidebar expand `General` and select `Keys`. The list of commands and their keyboard associations will be on the right. You can use filter to quickly find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**How to switch between open tabs:**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> will give you a list of open tabs that you can scroll through.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + (left or right arrows) does switch tabs, but it in a very odd way.

Best Approach is : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

**How to compile:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> is the general way.

**A few more useful shortcuts:**

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2010/10/eclipse-tutorial-most-useful-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> will compile your project.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to clean

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to build

Use both in this order to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

On My Linux <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> compiles code in `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

To run code in eclipse use the followed shortcut key

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f11</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in eclipse to get of shortcut list

Comment: This is what [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10979328/1364007) says - but posted six years later.